# What's the difference between rootless Docker, running a container as a non-root user, and Podman?

Tags: docker, containers, podman

Recently I've been trying to run my Docker application as a non-root user. I've seen there are several options available to me:

1. Install rootless Docker : apparently this is a "non-root" version of Docker that runs containers as users other than root.
2. Use normal (rootful) Docker, but run containers with `docker run` with the `--user` flag.
3. User Podman to run the container.

I am not familiar with any of these solutions, I've only ever used Docker as root. So what are the differences and advantages/disadvantages of these methods?

Isn't the result exactly the same, i.e., a container running as non-root user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different things.

- `docker run --user` sets the UID to be used *inside* the container. It is useful to limit the privileges of the specific program which run within the container itself
- rootless docker means running the `docker` daemon itself as a non-privileged user. A flaw in `docker` itself will be contained without giving root permissions on the host system.  From docker's [docs:](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/)

> Rootless mode allows running the Docker daemon and containers as a
> non-root user to mitigate potential vulnerabilities in **the daemon** and
> the container runtime.

- `podman` is a daemon-less reimplementation of `docker`. Not having a central daemon to run/manage all the container instances is supposed to be more secure and lightweight

Comment: Should it mean that a container launched with `--user subuser` would **never** be able to access a directory on the host which is owned by `root` (which has permissions set to 700) ? I have a container launched as a sub-user, with a volume from the host, but if I `docker exec` that container, I'm still able to read/write the volume content FROM that container, including deleting root-owned files.

Comment: `docker run --user` sets the user for only the one command you run using that command. As you noted, you can always run another command as another user -- `docker exec` also has a `--user` argument.

Comment: _docker run --user sets the user for only the one command you run using that command_ does it also define the internal permissions of the container ?